# Monitor 1 turns off

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, xorg, display

I just recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 12.10. Since the upgrade I have had problems with my displays. [This Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdrm/+bug/1083585) was one of them. Now however it seems almost randomly my primary monitor losses signal. Its a 42" TV over HDMI but my second (regular LG over analog) stays on, however it's frozen. I end up having to power cycle my machine when ever this happeneds. I have had the same set up for months and ever since I upgraded it's become an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. when I upgraded it got rid of jockey, and the nvidia drivers. Reinstalled jockey from USC and I'm good.